# Display OpenCV Video with PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, opencv, video, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a really simple GUI that displays video captured from webcam. I do know how to show the frames with openCV window:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
```

This creates an extra window which shows the frames. My question is: **how do I show those frames in a qt window?**

I started with images first. I created a QLabel and used it as a container to display the image. And it worked. Can I show video frames in a similar way?

```
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(myImagePath)
self.imageBox.setPixmap(pixmap)
self.imageBox.show()
```

EDIT: I tried the similar approach with frames, but it crashed. (stuck in while loop? I had to force quit python)

```
def openCamera(self):
    self.capturing = True
    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while self.capturing:
        _, frame = self.cap.read()
        videoFrame = QtGui.QImage(frame, 200, 200,
                                  QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        convertFrame = QtGui.QPixmap(videoFrame)
        self.imageBox.setPixmap(convertFrame)
        self.imageBox.show()
```

I use:

- python 3.5.2
- OpenCV 3.1.0
- PyQt5
- Windows 10

Thanks in advance!

Comment: didn't you try yet ? so don't waiste your and our time and first try. Later come with error message.

Comment: BTW one `frame` is only image so it can be display as image. Maybe it may need to convert to Qt image but maybe not.

Comment: Sorry I didn't put it on. I did try before I ask for a solution. I'll edit my post. Code caused a crash and I had to force quit python.

Comment: you can't use long-running code like `while True` in code because GUI frameworks run own `while` loop which do all stuff - it gets events from key/mouse, sends it to widgets, runs you functions, (re)draws widgets. You can use some `Timer` or event in Framework to run your function periodically.